# Woocommerce custom endpoint stopped working - ERROR 404

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is a code to create, define and rename/reorder custom endpoint for Woocommerce My Account page. Everything was fine until I updated Woocommerce and Avada. Now gives an ERROR 404 page when clicking on the new menu item, the URL being:

```
http://pplkonyv.hu/my-account/my-custom-endpoint
```

What should I modify?

```
function my_custom_endpoints() {
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-custom-endpoint', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_endpoints' );

/**
 * Add new query var.
 *
 * @param array $vars
 * @return array
 */
function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my-custom-endpoint';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0 );

/**
 * Flush rewrite rules on theme activation.
 */
function my_custom_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-custom-endpoint', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/**
 * Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu.
 *
 * @param array $items
 * @return array
  */
function my_custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {

    // Insert your custom endpoint.
    $items['my-custom-endpoint'] = __( 'My Custom Endpoint', 'woocommerce' );

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' );

/**
 * Endpoint HTML content.
 */

function my_custom_endpoint_content() {
    echo ( '<h2>Előfizetések</h2>' );
    echo do_shortcode( '[ld_profile]' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_my-custom-endpoint_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );

function wpb_woo_my_account_order() {
    $myorder = array(
        'edit-account'       => __( 'Felhasználónév és jelszó', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'       => __( 'Címek', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'             => __( 'Megrendelések', 'woocommerce' ),
        'my-custom-endpoint' => __( 'Előfizetések', 'woocommerce' ),
        'customer-logout'    => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $myorder;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'wpb_woo_my_account_order' );
```

Comment: What is the URL that results in a 404?

Comment: http://www.pplkonyv.hu/my-account/my-custom-endpoint/

Comment: It should display a headline and under it a shorcode generated LearnDash list...